# QT Sqlite UPDATE statement prepare error

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am trying to `prepare` a SQL statement using QT's built-in Sqlite engine.

The following statement:

```
UPDATE collections SET collection_type=:v1 WHERE 
(collections.collection_name = 'asfg')
```

fails in `QSqlQuery`'s `prepare` statement (`prepare` returns `false`).

`QSqlError err = db.lastError();` gives no error message...

However if I execute the same statement (by replacing  `:v1` with a number) in the sqlite prompt it succeeds.

What am I doing wrongly?

**Edit:**

What I was  doing wrongly was to not to have checked the database structure. The table was missing. Too bad I can't downvote my own post :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `:v1` with `?` and then use

```
query.addBindValue(v1);
```

`v1` is variable containing value.

Comment: The colon instead of a question mark is a valid placeholder in SQLite, and seems valid in QSqlQuery, too. However this wouldn't make the prepare statement fail.

Comment: And `?v1` is not a [valid placeholder](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).

Comment: @Murphy please don't make any more changes to my post. Your edits was invalid.

Comment: @CL Indeed, it isn't; mea culpa. "?" and `addBindValue(v1)` should work together, and ":v1" and `bindValue(":v1", v1)` should, too, but obviously you're not supposed to mix them.

Comment: @CL previous version is not what I wrote. That was invalid edit. Now it fixed.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks for all the effort!